# Drive a 3phase motor using its position given by AD2S1210

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I have drive a 3phase motor using Hall sensor, now with a new 3 phase motor and
AD2S1210 IC,  I can get motor position.
How i can drive the motor by position similar to Hall sensor?

Comment: We cannot see what your eyes can, so we have no idea of what sort of motor or electronics you have. Please enlighten us with more information. Lots more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a six-step motor brushless with resolver feedback:

First, determine the type of resolver.  A "1x" resolver is most common, meaning the resolver output changes 360 degrees for each revolution.  If you have a "2x" resolver, the resolver output changes 360 degrees for each 180 degrees of resolution and so forth.

Next, determine the number of poles of the motor.  This can usually be done by counting the number of magnets.  You will need the motor to go through the six steps as the rotor rotates through two magnet positions.  For example, in a four-pole motor (two north and two south magnets) you will need to go through all six steps twice per full revolution of a motor, so with a 1x resolver, you will need to switch phases 12 times per 360 measured degrees, or once every 30 degrees.

You then switch phases every thirty degrees in the following sequence:

High Side-Low Side

A-B  (Starting Location)

A-C  (Starting Location + 30)

B-C  (Starting Location + 60)

B-A  (Starting Location + 90)

C-A  (Starting Location + 120)

C-B  (Starting Location + 150)

A-B  (Starting Location + 180 ; re-start of sequence)

and so on.

You may have to reverse the sequence and/or rename phases depending upon how the motor is wired.  You will also have to determine the optimum switching position, but each of the phases would occur in thirty-degree increments from this position for a four-pole motor and 1x resolver.  Once you get the motor turning, you can find the "sweet spot" by running the motor in both directions, and adjusting the angular offset until the waveforms are similar and symmetrical.